# Firebase get uid when using fetchSignInMethodsForEmail

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm searching my users for email addresses which have accounts, but I also want to get the uid of the user that is associated with that account. Here is the code I'm using to get see if the user has an account. How can I also get the uid of that user?

```
firebase.auth().fetchSignInMethodsForEmail('someemail@email.com')
.then(providers => {
  if (providers.length === 0) {
     console.log('not a user');

  } else {
    console.log('is a user');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is not possible with the client sdk, but you can do in order to retrieve user id by email is to create a cloud function that get the required user's email use the function `getUserByEmail` which is availible in the admin sdk and send the uid back to the client

Comment: Does this give the user any sort of admin privileges in which they could harm my database with

Comment: No, because the user doesn't have access to the admin sdk, he only get the uid as a respone.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Admin SDK. You can call auth.getUserByEmail to get all record of that particular user you pass in getUserByEmail(email)

```
admin.auth().getUserByEmail(email)
  .then(function(userRecord) {
    // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
    console.log('Successfully fetched user data:', userRecord.toJSON());
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
   console.log('Error fetching user data:', error);
  });
```

Please see the detailed document here https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users

Comment: I am not using the Admin SDK, does this give the user any sort of admin privileges in which they could harm my database with?

Comment: As far as I know, this getUserByEmail() function is only available in Admin SDK.

Comment: Would you like to demonstrate what you want to do with other users after getting their id?

Comment: Basically I have a page where users can search for other users based on their email address and if it finds a user, it adds that to my database under the current users 'friends' key. But I need to get the uid of the user it finds to log their uid as I need it for future tasks.

Comment: Hmmm. Why you don't save their emails in friend list? Emails are also unique.

Comment: If you really need an id then you need to make another nested js object (table) in firebase for example users. When the user signs up, save its object in the user's tree of the firebase e.g users: {uid: {email: "", name: "", ---}}. 
For this, You can write some custom code to fetch all the users, match the email and get the id of that user